# Small question concerning cone of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am sure that I am heavily misunderstanding something, and I would be glad if someone could be so nice to help me out: this is exercise 1.13. in Joseph J. Rotman  „An Introduction to Algebraic Topology“, which states that for each $0\leq t<1$ the map $x\mapsto [x,t]$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ to a subspace of $CX:=X\times [0,1]/X\times \{1\}$. I see the bijectivity, but I‘m struggling to see that it is open: if $U\subset X$ is open, then we need to see that $[U,t]$ is open in $CX$, which is the same as asking that $\pi^{-1}([U,t])=U\times \{t\}$ is open in $X\times [0,1]$, where $\pi$ is the projection. But as $\{t\}$ is not open in $[0,1]$, I don‘t see this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you need are maps going both ways which are mutually inverse.

Comment: It only needs to be open **in** $X \times \{t\}$ and it is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - this was the point where I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cone is a  Hausdorff space so a continuous injective $f: X \to CX$ is automatically a homeomorphism onto its image (an embedding) by compactness of $X$.

And if you lack compactness then just use that $C\times \{t\}$ is closed for closed $C \subseteq X$. ( compactness is often assumed to ensure that $CX$ is metrisable, so I assumed it too at first, but it's not needed for this fact.) So $x \to [(x,t)]$ is a closed embedding (with closed image) regardless.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it is not assumed that $X$ is compact, so this argument does not work here, or am I mistaken?